# how to use wildcard in Crystal report selection expert

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i found this on another forum

set your default value 'ALL' for parameter

add if statement to Select Expert:

```
If {?Parameter}='ALL' 
Then {Database.Field} like '*' 
Else {Database.Field} = {?Parameter} and
{fctime_ts} >= {@StartDate} and 
{fctime_ts} < {@EndDate}
```

that didnt work, for some reason it isnt using the date constraints. So then i tried the following.

```
{fpartno} = IIF({?PartNbr} = 'All', '*' , {?PartNbr})
```

that works great if i use an actual part number, but when i use the defaul ALL it doesnt work at all.

this is my complete selection formula:

```
fpartno} = IIF({?PartNbr} = 'All', '*' , {?PartNbr}) and 
{fctime_ts} >= {@StartDate} and 
{fctime_ts} < {@EndDate}
```

anyone know how to either make the mentioned answer on this forum work with dates or how ot make this way work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a problem with what you recommended, but i found this answer.

This is how it works, it checks to see if PartNbr is equal to 'All'. If it does then it skips to the date restraints. By skipping, it will in turn select all the parts in that date range. if PartNbr doesn't equal 'All', it will take PartNbr and get the parts with that number within the date range.

This solution worked great for me, just htought id update if someone came by

```
({?PartNbr} = 'All'
or
{?PartNbr}= {intran.fpartno}) and
{intran.fctime_ts} >= {@StartDate} and
{intran.fctime_ts} <= {@EndDate}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(If {?Parameter}='ALL' Then
  {Database.Field} LIKE '*' 
Else
  {Database.Field} = {?Parameter}
)
and {fctime_ts} >= {@StartDate}
and {fctime_ts} < {@EndDate}
```