# Wildcard Parameter CR SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, crystal-reports

The following code I have written works find. Outputs what I expect.

```
select distinct
     mi_tm.st_event_time,
     mi_tm.st_location,
     mi_tm.st_log_class,
     mi_tm.st_qty,
     mi_tm.st_reason,
     mi_tm.st_reason_data,
     mi_tm.st_sku_code,
     mi_tm.st_ulid,
     mi_tm.st_user_id,
     x_prod.description,
     x_supplier.supplier_name
from
     mi_tm, x_prod,
     x_igd, x_supplier
where
     mi_tm.st_date >= {?Start} and
     mi_tm.st_date <= {?End} and
     mi_tm.st_sku_code = x_prod.prod_code (+) and
     mi_tm.st_sku_code = x_igd.prod_code (+) and
     x_igd.supplier_no = x_supplier.supplier_no (+) and
     mi_tm.st_sku_code like  '{?SKU}' and
     mi_tm.st_log_class in ('TM_ADJUST_QTY', 'TM_CREATE', 'TM_DELETE')
```

However for this line

```
   mi_tm.st_sku_code like  '{?SKU}' and
```

I would like it to be able to expect a wildcard parameter, that will return all values run between the dates. Just querying a % seems to crash my report. and I have tried adding '%' around the parameter. But I either get an invalid number error, or SQL not ended properly. I would be grateful for any help on this issue.

Edit: Place this at the bottom

```
If {?SKU} = '*' then
mi_tm.st_sku_code like '*'
else mi_tm.st_sku_code like  '{?SKU}'
```

Comment: Please check this post, I think it has you answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6295588/how-to-use-wildcard-in-crystal-report-selection-expert?rq=1

Comment: I have tried something like that which I have put in an edit, but the sql isn't ending properly

Comment: "If" is not an SQL keyword. It would be something like this: mi_tm.st_sku_code like CASE {?SKU} WHEN '*' THEN '%' ELSE '{?SKU}' END